# http request - camel's concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency, jetty, httprequest, apache-camel

Does any method of camel's consumer exist which is able to process >20 http requests per second? I try to work with restlet and jetty components, but failed with both.

For example, I set this config for a jetty component:

```
 <bean id="jetty" class="org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent">
   <property name="httpClientMinThreads" value="10"/>
   <property name="httpClientMaxThreads" value="254" />
   <property name="minThreads" value="10"/>
   <property name="maxThreads" value="254" />
</bean>
```

and hoped that everything will be OK, but nothing.

My route config:

```
from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8888" + linkRequest+"?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
          .onException(Exception.class)
            .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "${exception.stacktrace}")
            .useOriginalMessage()
            .handled(true)
            .setBody(simple("Something went wrong"))
          .end()

            .process(new MyFirstProcessor())//here I get httpHeaders,create entity A
            .to("jpa:RequestEntity")
            .process(new MySecondProcessor())//set some filed in entity A and send it
            .to("bean:service?method=process")//here I recieve entity A and create entity B
            .to("jpa:ResponseEntity")
            .process(new MyThirdProcessor())//here response is created;
```

Please explain to me how I can configurate parameters of camel (I glance at the threading model configuration), jetty-component or restlet component - so that my router can handle all incoming requests.

**UPDATE**
These problems were caused by the settings of the connection pool to the database.

Comment: So what is the exact error you see on the client and/or server side? How long does the processing of each individual request take from the point in time where you receive the request until the end of the route?

Comment: What's the result of the code above? Does it fail? New incoming requests are discarded or queued?

Comment: Have you considered scaling horizontally with multiple `Fuse Fabric` containers?

Comment: No, we didn't even consider this option :)